# How to create themes with style inheritance in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a WPF application that uses styles extensively, and in particulare style inheritance (using BasedOn) to describe its appearance. So, throughout the application's main files (in `<Application.Resources>` and `<Control.Resources>`) I have defined styles such as the following:

```
<Color x:Key="MusicTextColor">Red</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MusicTextColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource MusicTextColor}" />
<Style x:Key="MusicText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MusicTextColorBrush}" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MusicTitle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MusicText}" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
 </Style>
```

And in the UI I would use it normally like this to theme contents:

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource MusicTitle}">Artist:</TextBlock>
<Rectangle Background="{DynamicResource MusicTextColorBrush}" />
```

Now to theme the application, I am loading a theme.xaml file containing the theme changes in a `<ResourceDictionary>` at runtime and merge its resource dictionary with the application resources. The file might e.g. contain the following, which is supposed to change the color and font for all "music" labels:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... >
    <Color x:Key="MusicTextColor">Green</Color>
    <Style x:Key="MusicText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MusicTextColorBrush}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is, this does not work. Neither the color change nor the font change is picked up. Note that the font IS actually changed (and this confirms that a resource merge takes place) if I use any of the redefined styles directly (e.g. "MusicText"), but not the derived one. The explanation is most likely that the `BasedOn` attribute uses a `StaticResource` binding, so it will not find the redefined styles, even after the merge. As I learned, `BasedOn` does not allow a `DynamicResource` binding that I would need here.

To me this looks like a common problem - theming an application with style inheritance at runtime, but I have not found a realistic solution until now.

Of course I could stop using style inheritance at all, but that would result in a lot of redunant code.

Also, I could copy ALL derived styles into the theme, but that would be error-prone and prevent further application updates (without manually updating each theme with each change).

Did I miss something or is there really no convenient solution for this?

Comment: What if you change your `DynamicResource` to `StaticResource`? Just organize the styling that it can find the dependencies.

Comment: I have to ask, did you consult thy search engine before asking?

Comment: @lll: If I do that, none of the original styles can be overwritten by the theme (i.e. not even directly derived ones).

Comment: @ChrisW.: Yes of course I did that. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: Still an open issue. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.